# Are Sacred and Profane bonuses the same thing?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, bonus-type

The way they are presented, Sacred and Profane bonuses very much look like two sides of the same coin. That said, is there any indication in the rules of whether they stack (as different bonuses) or not (as similar bonuses)?

Comment: Is there a Samuel L Jackson racial trait that gives you a +20 to your Profane bonus?

Comment: @krillgar No, but Bards can take the "Tarantino" prestige class to gain that bonus, in addition to a few others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Though many sources of these bonuses give you a sacred bonus if you are good and a profane bonus if you are evil, there is nothing special about these bonuses, they work like any other type of bonus. If you manage to get both sacred and profane modifiers at the same time, yes, they stack.